# finitely presented group with finite generating set

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, geometric-group-theory

I`m supposed to solve a question for my geometric group theory course that states:

> Suppose $H$ subgroup of the group $G$, with a retraction from $G$ to $H$ and $G$ is finitely presentable. Show that $H$ is finitely presentable.

I found a way to go about this described in the book Invitations to Geometry and Topology edited by Simon Salamon and Martin Bridson. See [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=VB_f6xnmvikC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=retraction+finitely+presented+group&source=bl&ots=ztGodk5Snt&sig=ACfU3U2HgDhIepWORWOk64MPvGomNSA2xQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiImrXUrcfnAhXGOcAKHRQiDxcQ6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=retraction%20finitely%20presented%20group&f=false).

They give the following steps:

1. Show $H$ is finitely generated(Done).
2. Take a finite generating set for $H$ and expand it to a finite generating set for $G$ by adding elements from the kernel of the retraction(Done).
3. Argue that one can take a finite presentation with this generating set for $G$(Not done, here is my problem).
4. Add the generators from the kernel to the relations to arrive at a finite presentation for $H$(Seems straightforward).

So my question is:

> For point 3, do I need to construct something or is it true that if you have a finitely presentable group and a finite generating set that you can find finitely many accompanying relations to make it into a finite presentation? If so, why, if not, why also :)?

Thanks in advance.

---

P.s., my first post here, hope it`s all up to the standard

Answer (score 2):

To answer point 3, if you already have a finite presentation $G=\langle g_1,...,g_m \mid r_1,...,r_n\rangle$, and you then add some new elements $h_1,...,h_p \in G$ to the generating set, then to get a presentation of $G$ all you need to do is add some new relators to the original presentation for $G$, one new relator for each new generator $h_i$, of the form
$$h_i^{-1} w_i(g_1,..,g_m)
$$
where $w_i(g_1,..,g_m)$ expresses $h_i$ as a word in the original generators of $G$.

Comment: There is a slightly stronger (and not particularly difficult) result that, if $\langle X \mid R \rangle$ is a presentation of a finitely presentable group $G$ and $X$ is finite, then $G = \langle X \mid R' \rangle$ for some finite subset $R'$ of $R$.